# IndexError: list index out of range - throwing error in Python?

Tags: python, list, error-handling, append, indexoutofboundsexception

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for i in a:
    if a[i] % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(a[i])
```

The code above keeps throwing the error - `"IndexError: list index out of range"`

I cannot understand what to do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you perform `for i in a` you are iterating over the **elements** of `a`, not the indices!

You are trying to access: `a[1]` and then `a[4]` and then `a[9]` and then `a[16]` `->` Which is the one that is causing the `IndexError`.

If you want to iterate only over the indices try:

```
>>> for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] % 2 == 0 :
            l.append(a[i])


>>> print (l)
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

If you need both the value and index use `for index, value in enumerate(a):`.

Answer (score 3):

When you are iterating over `a`, you are looking at the value rather than the position of that value in the list.

You could use just the value like so:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for val in a:
    if val % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(val)
```

Or alternately, if you need both the position and the value then you can use the `enumerate` function, like so:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for pos, val in enumerate(a):
    if a[pos] % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(a[pos])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways:

```
for e in a:
  if e % 2 == 0 :
    l.append(e)
```

or

```
for i in range(len(a)):
  if a[i] % 2 == 0 :
    l.append(a[i])
```

or

```
for i, e in enumerate(a):
  if e % 2 == 0 :
    l.append(e)
```

or

```
for i, e in enumerate(a):
  if a[i] % 2 == 0 :
    l.append(a[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for that:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l = [i for i in a if i%2 == 0]

print(l)
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100]
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehesions can be used to make it one-liner
`l=[x for x in a if x%2==0]`
And as stated in ather answers your problem is that you are using list item as its indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *filter* for your task:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
print filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, a)
```

Answer (score 0):

as in other answers, `i` takes the values from `a`, which are `[1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]`
in the loop when `i` takes the value "`16`", `a[i]` will be out of range!! (`16 > len(a)`)

**for debugging i always suggest printing...**
in this case if you print the value of`i` in the loop, you will find the problem yourself

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for i in a:
    if a[i] % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(a[i])

...
if a[1] % 2 == 0:
...
if a[4] % 2 == 0:
...
if a[9] % 2 == 0:
...
if a[16] % 2 == 0:
```

index error, because the biggest index is 9 in array a...
so u have to use this:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(i)
```

or this example:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= []
for i in a:
    if i % 2 == 0 :
        l.append(i)
```

or the 1 line solution:

```
a = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100]
l= [x for x in a if x%2 == 0]
```